# How do I implement an Angular-like filter function in php?

Tags: php

I have a page that is full of tables (generated by a foreach loop) and every row displays, among other things, a month.

Now I want to give the user the ability to choose a month and have only the table rows for that current month displayed (or no table at all if that month is missing from the table). A bit like the filtering function in Angular JS.

I'm still a bit new to php and the only solution I can up with is to handle the whole thing somewhat clumsily with modifying CSS classes and having the superfluous rows hidden by CSS.

What would be a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you, please show us some Code....? A fragment of it would do us some good...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related with the filter alternate of angular into php.
As you know php is server side. So, if you want to get the filter after a reload or by ajax method, you need a `$_GET` variable.
 
Use a different query string in your url for each click of each button. Then retrieve the `GET` variable and use it to get data from database for relevant category.